# Как настроить настроить загрузку модулей webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Пробую настроить самостоятельно webpack первый раз на старом проекте, и не могу понять почему не грузится ничего кроме html, выдает ошибки при запуске:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/pages/index.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Также 404 для скрипта и пикчей

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './scripts/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'), 
            filename: 'index.html', 
            inject: false
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
          },
          compress: true,
          port: 8080,
          hot: true
        },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Подключение css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../pages/index.css">
```

Подключение JS:

```
<script type="module" src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
```

В Css файле только импорты модулей css, и ничего более

PS Делал все это, собирая инфу из нескольких разных туториалов, поэтому уже совсем потерялся где может быть ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `HtmlWebpackPlugin` сам подключает js, удалите в шаблоне `<script type="module" src="../scripts/index.js"></script>`.
- `css-loader` интегрирует css в html (создает тэг `<style>` с вашим CSS), если вы хотите упаковывать css в отдельный файл, то вместо `style-loader` используйте [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).
- В html шаблоне удалите `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../pages/index.css">`, т.к. для `css-loader` подключение файла не требуется, а MiniCssExtractPlugin
  сам подключит css файл.
- `CleanWebpackPlugin` [утратил свою актуальность](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder), достаточно в output добавить `clean: true`

p.s.
Обратите внимание, что в `output` имя бандла `index.bundle.js`, а подключить вы пытаетесь `index.js`, в целом, см. п. 1.

> Делал все это, собирая инфу из нескольких разных туториалов, поэтому уже совсем потерялся где может быть ошибка

У вебпака есть официальная документация и [гайды](https://webpack.js.org/guides/).

Comment: Сделал все пункты из вашего ответа. При запуске build работает, а при запуске test все равно выдает ошибки. При удалении подключения css и js файлов в html не помогло, но я поменял название js файла и хотя бы он заработал, и начали грузиться картинки. Осталось разобраться с css.
Я не совсем понимаю где находятся файлы css после сборки?

Comment: еще раз про css-loader прочитайте. Он не создает css файлов, он интегрирует css внутрь html файла в тэг style. Чтобы создавались css файлы нужно вместо css-loader подключить MiniCssExtractPlugin (ссылка в ответе)